# How to disable auto open Captive portal in Android marshmallow?

Tags: android, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I have work with open ssid of wifi.

when auto wifi connected to ssid that time automatically default browser open and redirect to Captive Portal.

I have find the method *ignoreNetwork()* in *CaptivePortal* class in Android library.

Show below link:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/CaptivePortal.java

How can I use ignoreNetwork() method in my project?

How to create instance of CaptivePortal class?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a CaptivePortal class instance. 
You can disable the Captive Portal Detection by changing Android Settings with `adb` tool.

Run in your host command prompt:

```
//Android 4+
adb shell settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0

//Since Android 7
adb shell settings put global captive_portal_mode 0
```

More details: https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/FAQ#61-what-is-androids-captive-portal-check

Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251866/how-to-disable-captive-network-assistant-into-android-device?rq=1) maybe it helps.